# Jsoup Java HTML parser : Executing Javascript events

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing, dom-events

Can I fill out forms, execute events and Javascript functions in Jsoup? If yes how can I? Or should I go for another parser.

Comment: How did you fix this? could you get what you want

Answer (score 37, accepted):

JSoup is just an HTML parser/"tidyfier" - not a browser emulator. To interact with HTML pages (execute javascript, fill out forms, etc.) you should use a tool like [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) or [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: OK Ok. I have a problem, I have two dropdowns on HTML page. When one drop down is changed, the options in other dropdown change. I want to change the first dropdown value in Java code, and then get the new values in the second dropdown, how can I do it in HTML unit?

Answer (score 3):

Use Selenium - if you use Selenium 2 WebDriver API, the main classes there are **WebDriver**, FirefoxDriver, and JavascriptExecutor.