# How to crawl web page which run Javascript with cookies check before showing main content

Tags: javascript, java, xml, rss, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl and parse following RSS feed:
http://english.alarabiya.net/.mrss/en/sports.xml

When I open it in browser it gives me the normal RSS feed that I want to parse. But when I download it inside Java it shows me the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(c_name) { // Local function for getting a cookie value
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start!=-1) {
        c_start=c_start + c_name.length + 1;
        c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);

        if (c_end==-1) 
            c_end = document.cookie.length;

        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays) { // Local function for setting a value of a cookie
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires=" + exdate.toGMTString()) + ";path=/";
}
function getHostUri() {
    var loc = document.location;
    return loc.toString();
}
setCookie('YPF8827340282Jdskjhfiw_928937459182JAX666', '105.183.123.12', 10);
try {  
    location.reload(true);  
} catch (err1) {  
    try {  
        location.reload();  
    } catch (err2) {  
        location.href = getHostUri();  
    }  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>This site requires JavaScript and Cookies to be enabled. Please change your browser settings or upgrade your browser.</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using simple stream reading, here is my code:

```
     try {
            URL url = new URL("http://english.alarabiya.net/.mrss/en/sports.xml");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            in.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Is there anyone know how to parse the main RSS content and bypass the Javascript part with cookies? Or any ideas?

P.S.: I'm using Rome library to crawl the RSS feed, but I think the problem out of its scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) library and use `setJavascriptEnabled(true)` there

Your question is simillar with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857780/how-to-extract-source-html-from-webpage) one