# Fetching the website with Jsoup - page view source and Jsoup shows different content

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I use Jsoup to scrap the website:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(String.valueOf(urls[0])).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
```

Here is the link:

http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=restaurant&find_loc=willowbrook%2C+IL&ns=1#l=p:IL:Willowbrook::&sortby=rating&rpp=40

I have added **rpp=40** parameter to the link in the command line to display 40 results per page. I'm able to see all the results in page view source.
I know that Jsoup is for the static content only and cannot fetch the websites that use AJAX/JS Libraries technique to generate content. However why Jsoup cannot retrieve the same content as I can see in the browser via page view source? Page view source shows 40 results whereas Jsoup is able to retrieve elements from only 10 results? How can I obtain every elements visible via page view source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer** Jsoup can't execute the Javascript.

**Long answer**

```
http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=restaurant&find_loc=willowbrook%2C+IL&ns=1#l=p:IL:Willowbrook::&sortby=rating&rpp=40
```

The webpage your are looking for accepts the Http Get with the parameters. In the normal browser it accepts the params and loads the page . But **Not with willowbrook checked**(in your example). It loads the JS after it loads the page and the Javascript does the check box for **Fliters** the serach results. Therefore when you use Jsoup you are getting more results because it loads  'state=IL' without 'willowbrook' filtered.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I get more results only when use page view source but jsoup shows only ten results. How can I execute JavaScript then?

Comment: [You can't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344258/jsoup-java-html-parser-executing-javascript-events). You are getting less result maybe because their application logic isn't what I stated in my answer. But the idea is , the Javascript plays around with the data.