# Page content couldn't be seen by Jsoup and HttpClient

Tags: java, httpclient, jsoup, html-parsing

Hi I want to scrap the information from a website  so I tried to use Jsoup (also tried HttpClient) to do so. I realize that both of them couldn't "see" certain content of the html page. so when I tried to print out the parsed html, I got the empty div like this. It prints out some other div just fine.
here's my code:

```
Class Main{

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    System.out.println(doc.getElementsByClass("needed content"));
  }
}
```

the result in the terminal is:

```
<div class="needed content"></div>
```

I am searching for answers on stackoverflow, some recommends using Jackson Library
[Java - How do I access a child of Div using JSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317089/java-how-do-i-access-a-child-of-div-using-jsoup/54318247#54318247)

some recommend embed a browser in java
[Is there a way to embed a browser in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249/is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-browser-in-java)

some recommend using htmlunit
[Fail to get full content of page with JSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309674/fail-to-get-full-content-of-page-with-jsoup)

I just tried combining Jsoup with html unit, same result here's the code:

```
        try(WebClient wc = new WebClient()){  
        wc.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        wc.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);  
        wc.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false); 
        wc.getOptions().setTimeout(10000); 
        HtmlPage page = wc.getPage("https://chainlinklabs.com/jobs");  
        String pageXml = page.asXml();  
        

         
        Document doc2 = Jsoup.parse(pageXml, url);   
        System.out.println(doc2.getElementsByClass("needed content"));
  
        System.out.println("Thank God!"); 
        }
```

My interpretation of the problem is Jsoup is not showing part of the html content because it contains javascript; am I heading to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need (and it is a waste of resources) to re-parse the page from HtmlUnit  into jsoup. All the select options are available in HtmlUnit also (see https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/gettingStarted.html) - and maybe more.

This simple code works for me - parts of the page are generated by an js script that starts asynchronous. Because of this you have to wait for these scripts before accessing the page.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String url = "https://chainlinklabs.com/jobs";

    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10_000);

        // System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        // System.out.println(page.asXml());
        // System.out.println("--------------------------------");


        System.out.println("- Jobs -------------------------");
        final DomNodeList<DomNode> jobTitles = page.querySelectorAll(".job-title");
        for (DomNode domNode : jobTitles) {
            System.out.println(domNode.asNormalizedText());
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you man! that makes total sense! much appreciated.