# jsoup not fetching all images off a page

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Tried to fetch images off this [page](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=hepatitis).

Using code shown below it fetches only side images like their logo etc.,  but doesn't fetch the image in which they have shown data.

```
public static void main (String args[])
{   
    Document doc;
    try {       
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=hepatitis").get();
        Elements desc =doc.select("img[src]");                               
        {
            for (Element link :desc)                
            System.out.println("text :"+link.absUrl("src"));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }  
}
}
```

I even tried to fetch images using their id like this:

```
Elements desc =doc.select("#scannerresult_0300_1 img[src]");
```

but it didn't return any result.

Comment: images i am trying to fetch are not there in view source id i was using to fetch them was obtained through inspect element jsoup cant fetch dynamic content ??

Comment: if your question is answered please consider accepting an answer. If you find the answer very helpful you can upvote it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website generates lots of content based on *javascripts*. nfortunately Jsoup doesn't support those, so the scripts are *not* executed, therefore no content is generated.

Please see this answer for more informations: [Fetch contents(loaded through AJAX call) of a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633294/fetch-contentsloaded-through-ajax-call-of-a-web-page/20642675#20642675)

Comment: this code fetches some of the image though it shouldnt at all afteall all images are coming from server side if it is managing to retrieve couple of images then there should be some way to fetch all as well

Comment: Those images you see, are not generated from scripts, they are set through proper html tags (see the source code of the website). You also can check the document jsoup parses, just print your `doc` and you'll see how jsoup "sees" the website. Another way is: disable all (or at least goolges ajax) javascripts, to see the plain site. As a solution, you can try either htmlunit or something similar (check my link).

Comment: I am gonna try HTML unit now . i did see view source of that site links of those images werent there they could be seen only through inspect element thanks for help