# Get Amazon data prices table with Jsoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to use Jsoup to get data table from the website:
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

I need to get the data from the tables and I'm trying the first table to begin but the page loads the table after some time.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(html).get();
Elements tableElements = doc.select("table");
Elements tableHeaderEles = tableElements.select("thead tr th");
Elements tableRowElements = tableElements.select(":not(thead) tr");
Instance ins = new Instance();
for (int i = 0; i < tableRowElements.size(); i++) {
    Element row = tableRowElements.get(i);
    System.out.println("row");
    Elements rowItems = row.select("td");
    for (int j = 0; j < rowItems.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println(rowItems.get(j).text());
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Add a userAgent and a timeout to your conection. Make sure you are getting the source code correctly. And then try out your css query on this site - http://try.jsoup.org/. When I tried out `thead` on the url, I did not get anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Jsoup**:

- Add a userAgent and a timeout to your connection.
- Make sure you get the source code correctly.
- Try out your CSS Selector query on http://try.jsoup.org/.

**PhantomJSDriver**:

If the problem is being caused by Javascript (since JSoup does not support Javascript), then I suggest Selenium + PhantomJSDriver (Ghostdriver), which is used for **GUI-less** browser automation. With this you can easily navigate through the pages, select elements, submit forms and also perform some scraping. *Javascript is also supported.*

You can got through the Selenium documentation [**here**](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). You will have to download [**phantomjs.exe**](http://phantomjs.org/) file.

A good tutorial forPhantomJSDriver is given in [**here**](http://seleniumworks.blogspot.in/2013/03/headless-browser-testing-using.html)

Config of PhantomJSDriver(from the tutorial):

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true); // not really needed: JS enabled by default
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "C://phantomjs.exe");
caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you cannot get the desired contents is that: Some contents are loaded by `Ajax`, which cannot be aware by the `Jsoup`.

Please refer to [Fetch contents(loaded through AJAX call) of a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633294/fetch-contentsloaded-through-ajax-call-of-a-web-page), it shows that **HtmlUnit**, and etc., will do for you.