# access inspect element content through java code with all the javascript and ajax loaded

Tags: java, javascript, url, html

Is there a way to access all the content shown in inspect element through java code? 
Tried jsoup, but it doesn't return javascript parts. Not able to access all the content through HtmlUnit as well.

Someone suggested [Java Script Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633294/fetch-contentsloaded-through-ajax-call-of-a-web-page/20642675#20642675) on Stackoverflow, but can't find any example to get the entire content from URL.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am still working on the problem, any suggestions?