# How to access updated HTML source after the Javascript on the page has been executed, in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsoup

I am trying to grab elements and their respective attributes from a webpage using Jsoup in java. However, I've realized that there is some javascript that runs after the page has been loaded that creates a table, which holds all of the information I am trying to access on the page.

Using java, I was wondering if there is any way to access the updated HTML source after the javascript has executed so that I can grab the elements in the table that I need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

jsoup doesn't support javascript execution, you'll have to use something else to load the page, grab the source and then pass it to jsoup to parse the info you want.

A couple libraries I have used in this situation:

- [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)
- [ui4j](https://github.com/ui4j/ui4j)

There are others but these are the two I have used and feel comfortable recommending.

Oops, just did some Googling, seems this is a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20642675/1585957)

Also, see this [list of headless browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/814929/1585957). Great answer, I have this one bookmarked.