# Cannot scrape price from website with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm having project in college which I need to build a software that tracks item prices based on URLs that the user should enter (currently only from Banggood.com).

I have just started to learn about scraping info from websites so I've manage to do that and I stuck just in the beginning. I managed to **scrape** the item title but unsuccessfull to do that with the item price. I upload my current code.

I could not managed get the right info from Jsoup site nor Google

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class ProjectLearning 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        print("Please enter your item URL: ");
        String userUrl = scan.next();
        print("Give me a sec..");
        
        Document document;
        try {
            //Get Document object after parsing the html from given url.
            document = Jsoup.connect(userUrl).get();

            String title = document.title(); //Get title
            print("Item name: " + title); //Print title.
            
            //Get price
            Elements price = document.select("div#item_now_price");
        
            for (int i=0; i < price.size(); i++) 
            {
                print(price.get(i).text());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        print("There you go");
    }

    public static void print(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Please enter your item URL: 
https://www.banggood.com/3018-3-Axis-Mini-DIY-CNC-Router-Standard-Spindle-Motor-Wood-Engraving-Machine-Milling-Engraver-p-1274569.html?rmmds=flashdeals&cur_warehouse=CN

Give me a sec..

Item name: 3018 3 axis mini diy cnc router standard spindle motor wood engraving machine milling engraver Sale - Banggood.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are getting the element with **id** `item_now_price` and not **class**.

Looking into the URL that you've entered, the element with the price looks like below:

```
<div class="item_now_price" oriattrmin="0" oriattrmax="0" noworiprice="149.9" oriprice="149.9" oriprice3="146.7" oriprice10="145.16" oriprice30="143.64" oriprice100="142.11">US$149.90</div>
```

The correct selector should be `Elements price = document.select("div.item_now_price");`

Look into https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax for learning more about the selectors.

**Update:**
So, I've looked in your code and the reason you are not getting the price as output is that the price is loaded through another Ajax request. Unfortunately `jSoup` cannot help you here.

For more information, look into this answer: [Fetch contents(loaded through AJAX call) of a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633294/fetch-contentsloaded-through-ajax-call-of-a-web-page)