# Read HTML page, after javascript (java)

Tags: java, javascript, html

in my project I need to read some web pages. Usually it is pretty easy: I read the source code using java classes, parse the output and save interesting data.

But sometimes it is harder; for example reading Google pages. I think it is because of javascript. Do you know to get the real web page code, I mean without javascript? For example if I analyse the page using the Firebug extension of Firefox I read exactly what I need: javascript is correctly replaced by its results. Any idea to do it using Java?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may try using [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/), also [read](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links)

Comment: JSoup doesn't execute JavaScript. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344258/jsoup-java-html-parser-executing-javascript-events

Comment: Thank you for your answers.. Do you know if Selenium works on Android?