# How to parse a page built on the client side with Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I need to parse one site, but the contents are dynamically generated by Javascript. Is there a way to parse content produced by javascript using Jsoup?

```
<form method="post" action="../ScreenResolution.aspx" id="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZHfXW6EsrLhbTy9klStsYFtE87Sw" /> 

<script src="/js/framework/WorkWithCookies.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">var iScreenWidth = window.screen.width; var iOutcomesGroupsPerRow = 1; if (1280 < iScreenWidth) { if (1680 < iScreenWidth) iOutcomesGroupsPerRow = 3; else iOutcomesGroupsPerRow = 2; } var objClassInstance = new WorkWithCookies('lsoutcomesgroupsperrow'); objClassInstance.WriteCookie(iOutcomesGroupsPerRow, null, null); window.location.href = window.location.href;window.location.reload();</script>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="2E0D1D88" />
</form>
```

Comment: Your question appears to be missing the very essence of a question

Comment: If you need to parse site, then just do it.

Comment: Scripts is writing everything on the page, and i can't read the page througth jsoup.

Comment: repeating your statement in a comment does not help to clarify what you want to do. I would suggest to formulate a question (hint - it ends with a `?`). Provide also what you expect to be the result of the parsing. For me it is not clear if you try to parse the contents of the script tag, or if the JavaScript loads/renders the actual page that you want to parse. If the latter case is true, you are out of luck, since JSoup does not interpret/run JavaScript. Look into selenium webdriver if you need this kind of functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jsoup Java HTML parser : Executing javascript events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344258/jsoup-java-html-parser-executing-javascript-events)

Comment: This site has a search function. Use it before posting a new question.

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing (Jsoup 1.8.3), it's not possible to parse a webpage that need a script to build its content.

Jsoup is an HTML parser. It doesn't support Javascript. If you want to parse webpages built with client side script, you can use tools like [ui4j](https://github.com/ui4j/ui4j) or [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).