# Load content dynamically with JSoup - data doesn't inflate

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to create an app which is parsing HTML data into `RecyclerView`. Using `JSoup`, I'm trying to make:

A static fragment as a homepage,

A dynamic fragment with content being changed on click in `NavigationView`.

Full code is on [GitHub](https://www.github.com/C0nverter/OpenSUSEHowTo), I've already opened an issue. The thing is content doesn't load properly - after inflating `Fragment` no data is being shown, although I can see a successful creation of `ArrayList` with my data in logs.
I think the problem is with the `ViewHolder` inside `ContentAdapter`. I've put the `Log.d` inside both `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` - no logs are shown during load process.

Every single data there is public, as the app is being created for local grant project - it'll also be published in Play Store when finished.

Thanks in advance for any help provided!

Comment: If contend is created dynamically then most likely it involves JavaScript which is not supported by Jsoup. More info: [Jsoup Java HTML parser : Executing javascript events](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7344258)

Comment: The `Fragment` itself is dynamic - content from Web is static, but depending on selected navigation item, is being changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer already.
I've created `Utils` class for storing the most important values and passing them to activities or fragments. All I had to do was to **reformat** `Utils` **to singleton pattern** - when I was calling `Utils` previously, no data was shown because of different instances. After making this class a singleton, data was collected and displayed properly.