# Jsoup parse triple nested span

Tags: java, android, parsing, jsoup, android-parser

I am in stuck with creating `cssQuery` for Jsoup for parsing html.

**What I want to parse:**

```
    ...    
    <div class="counterdiv">
        <div class="counter-group" id="c1">
        <div class="counter-heading collapsed inactive-header">
        <span class="counter-number">
        <span class="rts-counter">
        <span class="rts-nr-int rts1">1</span>
        <span class="rts-nr-int rts2">2</span>
        <span class="rts-nr-int rts3">3</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**What I want in output:** 123

**What I am getting  in output now:** null

What I've tried to get desirable output:

```
Element element = document.select
// Elements elements = document.select
// (".counterdiv.counter-group.counter-heading.inactive-header.rts-counter.rts-nr-int.rts1");
(".counterdiv.counter-group.counter-heading.inactive-header.counter-number span").first();
// (".counterdiv .counter-group .counter-heading inactive-header .counter-number span");
// (".counterdiv .counter-group .counter-heading inactive-header .counter-number span span span");
// ("div.counterdiv > div.counter-group > #c1 > div.counter-heading.inactive-header > span.counter-number > span");
```

And a lot of other such variations but `element` or `elements` always `null`.

**Where is my problem? What I am doing wrong while building `cssQuery`?**

Comment: edited my post, there were typos

Comment: Anyway `.counterdiv.counter-group...` doesn't look right. We use `.class1.class2` to describe `<element class="class1 class2">` not `<element class="class1><element class="class2">`. When you want to describe element which is a child of other element use `space` like `parentDescription  childDescription`.

Comment: BUT even if those selectors can't locate such elements then maybe problem isn't with selector but with HTML response you got from server. Maybe DOM it represents doesn't contain elements you are looking for. Try printing your document and see if elements you are searching they are present there in positions you expect. If they are not then maybe they are added dynamically by JavaScript (which `jsoup` doesn't support since it isn't browser emulator but parser)

Comment: yes, seems like JavaScript dynamically adding elements.

Comment: Related (or even duplicate since solution here is "to not use Jsoup but other tool which can handle JS"): [Jsoup Java HTML parser : Executing Javascript events](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7344258)