# Using Jsoup to get youtube href links

Tags: kotlin, web-scraping, youtube, web-crawler, jsoup

I'm currently using Jsoup to try and get the videoID of the Youtube videos after I perform a search. I'm trying the get the videoID from the href and to do that I am using the following code:

```
val doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.youtube.com/results")
                .data("search_query", s).get()

          for (a in doc.select("a[href]")) {
              Log.d("MAIN", a.attr("abs:href"))
          }
```

But currently, the result looks as so:
[image]

So I thought youtube was giving me a basic response because I didn't have the user agent. So I did that.

I tried adding the following based on this [previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581655/jsoup-useragent-how-to-set-it-right)

```
.ignoreContentType(true)
.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
.referrer("http://www.google.com")
.timeout(12000)
.followRedirects(true)
.execute().parse()
```

It still gives me the basic response. I wanted to compare the results of `Log.d("MAIN", doc.toString())` but there was only a slight difference in the meta tag and the nonce. And for some reason, I wasn't getting the full string version of the doc so I could not make further comparisons.

How can I get the youtube links after they were searched? (I want to get a link where it has "watch?v=XXXXXXX")
If possible I would like solutions in kotlin language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at raw youtube response (`doc`), you'll see, that it returns a lot of js code (inside `<script>` tags). This code contains instructions about building HTML, which you see in your browser. But `Jsoup` [is not a browser emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344258/jsoup-java-html-parser-executing-javascript-events) - it can't execute javascript code, so there are no `a[href]` elements you're looking for.

You need to either use another tool or parse javascript. Luckly, simple regex is enough in this case:

```kotlin
val doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.youtube.com/results").data("search_query", s).get()
val regex = "\"videoId\":\"(\\w+)\"".toRegex()
val videoIds = doc.select("script")
    .map { it.data() }
    .filterNot { it.isEmpty() }
    .flatMap { regex.findAll(it) }
    .map { it.groupValues[1] }
    .distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on the accepted response but I'd just like to add that some youtube video Ids have "-" in them so you're going to need to change your regex to reflect that:

```
val regex = "\"videoId\":\"([\\w|-]+)\"".toRegex()
```